MSI Installer throws error, "Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services"
The .NET Service
I have been scratching my head for quite some time to try and understand as to why exactly my installation fails with this error.
I created a basic .NET 4.8 windows service that have real basic functionality
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
#if DEBUG
            Service1 test = new Service1();
            test.OnDebug();
            Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
#else

            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
            {
                new Service1()
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
#endif

        }
    }
}

using Serilog;
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.File("<Log path>", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
            .MinimumLevel.Information()
            .CreateLogger();
        }

        public void OnDebug()
        {
            try
            {
                OnStart(null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex, ex.Message);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Log.Information("Service Started");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex, ex.Message);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            try
            {
                Log.Information("Service Stopped");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex, ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}

The WIX Project
I created my basic Wix project and added the service as a reference like usual.
Below is the Package.wxs file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?define Name = "Test" ?>
<?define Manufacturer = "Test" ?>
<?define Version = "1.0.0.0" ?>
<?define UpgradeCode = "1D38B1B5-0BD5-419B-9BAC-9F571D2F8048" ?>

<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
    <Package
        Name="$(Name)"
        Manufacturer="$(Manufacturer)"
        Version="$(Version)"
        UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)"
        Compressed="yes">

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A later version is already installed." />

        <Media Cabinet="cab1.cab" Id="1" EmbedCab="yes"></Media>

        <Feature Id="Service" Title="Test Service" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="ServiceExecutable" />
        </Feature>

    </Package>
</Wix>

My Components.wxs file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?define Name = "Test Service" ?>

<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="Components" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">

            <Component Id="ServiceExecutable" Bitness="always64">

                <File Id="Test.exe"
                      Source="$(var.Test.TargetDir)\Test.exe"
                      KeyPath="true" />

                <RemoveFile Id="ALLFILES" Name="*.*" On="both" />

                <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller"
                                Name="Service1"
                                Type="ownProcess"
                                DisplayName="$(Name)"
                                Description="This is a test service"
                                Start="disabled"
                                ErrorControl="normal" />

                <ServiceControl Id="StartService"
                                Name="Service1"
                                Start="install"
                                Stop="both"
                                Remove="uninstall"
                                Wait="true" />
            </Component>

        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>

And my Folders.wxs file
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
  <Fragment>
    <StandardDirectory Id="ProgramFiles6432Folder">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="!(bind.Property.Manufacturer) !(bind.Property.ProductName)" />
    </StandardDirectory>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>

When installing my service without the Service Control the service gets installed correctly and runs fine, however this makes the installer pretty useless since I don't have the functionality of the installer.
The error "Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services" only appears to be happening when I run it with the Service Control added.
I troubleshooted a bit with the log file and couldn't see anything out of the ordinary.
I ran the .msi file with PowerShell as admin and still came across this issue
I appended the Account attribute to the Service Install, that also didn't seem to make a difference.
I followed steps to add the account to the service group policies, but with no luck, still the same error. (See link below for steps I took) 
https://www.blackfog.com/knowledge-base/privileges-to-install-system-services/
At this stage I am ready to give up.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Sounds like your service is failing to start but "The error" does not provide enough information to really start guessing more than that.

Never mind. I see the error message is in the title of the question, not in the body of the question.

I updated the question to put the error message in the body of the question to be helpful to future answerers.

Solved
The error is quite misleading. 
The log file should have given me a clue about this, it possibly did but I could have missed it. The error indicates that it is a user privilege issue, instead it was missing DLL's
After inspecting the Directory where the files are stored, I saw that the DLL's are not included.
To add them I simply ran a cmd command with the wix toolset in the toolset's directory:
heat dir "C:\path\to\service\bin\Release" -cg BinFiles -dr INSTALLFOLDER -srd -var var.BinDir -gg -out "C:\path\to\wix\project\binfiles.wxs"
After the creation of the file I removed the service .exe from the binfiles.wxs to ensure it is not appended twice.
I edited the .wixproj to ensure the variable (BinDir) is included
<PropertyGroup>           
    <DefineConstants>BinDir=C:\path\to\service\bin\Release</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>

Finally added the component group reference to the Package.wxs file within the service feature tag:
<Feature Id="Service" Title="Test Service" Level="1">
    <ComponentRef Id="ServiceExecutable" />
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="BinFiles" />
</Feature>

Then re-built the service and ran the installer, boom bam, everything was successfully installed and started
